# How to distinguish between TinyMCE images_upload_handler is to upload pictures or paste pictures?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Setting `images_upload_handler` will auto open the upload image function.

I used `paste_data_images` and `automatic_uploads`, they also trigger `images_upload_handler`.

`images_upload_handler` failure callback is invalid for `paste_data_images`, but effective for image uploads, I don't know if it is a bug, I use TinyMce version is tinymce-react 2.4.0 tinymce 4.9.2

How can I distinguish between TinyMCE `images_upload_handler` is uploading pictures or pasting pictures triggered?

Please help me, thank you!

Can I disable image upload while using images_upload_handler?

Answer (score 0):

The method I am currently processing is to determine whether the `data.name()` of `images_upload_handler` contains `mce`, because I found that their naming structure is different.